# python integration issue, the function with exponential

Tags: python, function, integration, rule, exponential

I would like to integrate the function e^(-x**2/2) by simpson rule
but it is keep having an error and I don't know what is the problem.

```
a=eval(input('a:'))
b=eval(input('b:'))
n=eval(input('n:'))
def f(x):
    e**(-x**2/2)
h=(b-a)/n
s= f(a)+f(b)
def simpson_rule(f(x),a,b,n):

  #Approximation by Simpson's rule
  c=(a+b)/2.0
  h=abs(b-a)/2.0
  return h*(f(a)+4.0*f(c)+f(b))/3.0
def simpson_rule(f(x),a,b,n):
    """Approximates the definite integral of f from a to b by the composite Simpson's rule, using n subintervals"""
    for i in range (1,n,2):
        s+=4*f(a+i*h)
    for i in range(2,n-1,2):
        s+=2*f(a+i*h)
    return s*h/3
print simpson_rule(f(x),a,b,n)
```

Comment: Have you done any research? I looked up the rule and there was already a Python implementation on Wikipedia.

Comment: You do not have a `return` statement in your function `f()`. Also, where are you setting the value of `e`? Anyway, you should use `math.exp(u)` to calculate `e**u` . And it's not a good idea to use `eval()` on user input - you can use `int()` or `float()` to convert strings to integers or floating-point numbers, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You define 2 integration routines with the same name. Which one do you expect to run if you call `simpson_rule()`?
The first one is the special case where n=1. You might rename it accordingly.

Second, your call is `print simpson_rule(f(x),a,b,n)` but you only need to hand over `f()` to the function, like this `print simpson_rule(f,a,b,n)`.
You can see that `f` is a function, and `f()` is a function return value:

```html
def f(x):
    return x + 13

f
<function f at 0x0000000002253D68>
f(5)
18
```

Try it out and if you still have errors please post the error message(s).